# Bootstrap navbar collapses and disappears immediately

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

when i click on the navbar icon on my mobile/tablet the navabr opens but then it goes away, but the navbar still thinks that the navbar is open, when i reclick on the navbar icon it closes then (can't see it close), but when i click again to open it, it's still the same.

I added a gif(sorry for the low resolution) to show you what i get.[GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZXNU.gif)

The Navbar code:

```
<div class="navbar-fixed-top">
        <div id="menu">
        <div class="menu--topbar">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="menu-topbar--contact">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">                        
                        <li><a style="color:#fff" href="MAILTO:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><span href="mailto:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"></span>EMAILXXXXX</a></li>
                        <li><a style="color:#fff" href="tel:XXXXXXXXXX"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i><span href="tel:XXXXXXXXX"></span> XXXXXXXXX</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>                 
            </div>
        </div>

            <nav id="secondaryMenu" class="navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#secondaryNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="secondaryNavbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
                    <div class="login-btn hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm"> <a href="#" class="btn">Nefsani</a> </div>
                </div>
                <div id="secondaryNavbar" class="reset-padding navbar-collapse collapse ">
                    <ul class="secondary-menu-links nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="OverMezelf-Opleiding.aspx">Over mezelf</a></li>                    
                        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="relatietherapie.aspx" data-toggle="dropdown">Mijn aanbod<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="relatietherapie.aspx">relatietherapie</a></li>
                                <li><a href="individueletherapie.aspx">individuele therapie </a></li>
                                <li><a href="persoonlijkeconsultgesprekken.aspx">persoonlijke consultgesprekken</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="TariefEnTerugbetaling.aspx">Tarieven en terugbetaling</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.aspx">Contacteer mij</a></li>                     
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="secondary-menu-links nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-xs">
                        <li><a href="Default.aspx" class="btn">Nefsani</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

The Navbar CSS:

```
#secondaryMenu {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: #54bceb;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    z-index: 1;
}

    #secondaryMenu.sticky {
        position: fixed;
        box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,.14),0 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.28);
    }

    #secondaryMenu .navbar-toggle {
        border: none;
    }

        #secondaryMenu .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
            background-color: #fff;
        }

    #secondaryMenu a.navbar-brand {
        display: block;
        padding: 10px 0;
        margin-top: 18px;
        margin-left: 0;
        color: #303030;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: 700;
    }

        #secondaryMenu a.navbar-brand span {
            color: #4584b4;
        }

    #secondaryMenu .navbar-header .login-btn > .btn {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #303030;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 0;
        -webkit-transition: color .25s ease,background-color .25s ease-in-out;
        transition: color .25s ease,background-color .25s ease-in-out;
    }

        #secondaryMenu .navbar-header .login-btn > .btn:focus, #secondaryMenu .navbar-header .login-btn > .btn:hover {
            color: #303030;
            background-color: #fff;
            box-shadow: none;
            outline: 0;
        }

.secondary-menu-links li a {
    margin-right: 3px;
    padding: 24px 14px 21px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-weight: 700;
    -webkit-transition: color .25s ease,background-color .25s ease-in-out,border-color .25s ease;
    transition: color .25s ease,background-color .25s ease-in-out,border-color .25s ease;
}

.secondary-menu-links li:last-child a {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.secondary-menu-links > .dropdown > a > .caret {
    margin-left: 8px;
}

.secondary-menu-links li a .fa {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto 3px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.secondary-menu-links .open > a, .secondary-menu-links .open > a:focus, .secondary-menu-links .open > a:hover, .secondary-menu-links li a:focus, .secondary-menu-links li a:hover, .secondary-menu-links li.active > a, .secondary-menu-links li.active > a:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #fff;
}

.secondary-menu-links > .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.secondary-menu-links li .dropdown-menu {
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px 0;
    border-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0;
}

    .secondary-menu-links li .dropdown-menu li a {
        margin-right: 0;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        color: #303030;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 20px;
        border: none;
    }

.secondary-menu-links > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > li.active > a, .secondary-menu-links > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > li.active > a:focus, .secondary-menu-links > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > li.active > a:hover, .secondary-menu-links > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus, .secondary-menu-links > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #00678d;
}

.secondary-menu-links.navbar-right {
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.secondary-menu-links > li > a.btn {
    padding: 24px 30px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #303030;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-transition: color .25s ease,background-color .25s ease-in-out;
    transition: color .25s ease,background-color .25s ease-in-out;
}

    .secondary-menu-links > li > a.btn:focus, .secondary-menu-links > li > a.btn:hover {
        color: #303030;
        background-color: #fff;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
```

If you need any more informaton let me know.
thanks in advance!

Comment: Please tag correctly as the code your posting has nothing to do with vb.net & asp.net

Comment: I'm using vb.net and asp.net thats why i tagged it, but i will remove those tags then

Comment: In the code you give you only posted CSS and HTML so no need to tag it if the code doesn't appear

Comment: okay thnx for tip, sorry for the miss use of the tags

Comment: i cannot recreate the problem. check your console for any errors . in the fiddle it all works as expected ( also tried on mobile )

Comment: I've added a gif to show you how it looks like for me

Comment: try my code...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with all these includes, working fine now.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  #secondaryMenu {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: #54bceb;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    z-index: 1;
}

    #secondaryMenu.sticky {
        position: fixed;
        box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,.14),0 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.28);
    }

    #secondaryMenu .navbar-toggle {
        border: none;
    }

        #secondaryMenu .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
            background-color: #fff;
        }

    #secondaryMenu a.navbar-brand {
        display: block;
        padding: 10px 0;
        margin-top: 18px;
        margin-left: 0;
        color: #303030;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: 700;
    }

        #secondaryMenu a.navbar-brand span {
            color: #4584b4;
        }

    #secondaryMenu .navbar-header .login-btn > .btn {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #303030;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 0;
        -webkit-transition: color .25s ease,background-color .25s ease-in-out;
        transition: color .25s ease,background-color .25s ease-in-out;
    }

        #secondaryMenu .navbar-header .login-btn > .btn:focus, #secondaryMenu .navbar-header .login-btn > .btn:hover {
            color: #303030;
            background-color: #fff;
            box-shadow: none;
            outline: 0;
        }

.secondary-menu-links li a {
    margin-right: 3px;
    padding: 24px 14px 21px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-weight: 700;
    -webkit-transition: color .25s ease,background-color .25s ease-in-out,border-color .25s ease;
    transition: color .25s ease,background-color .25s ease-in-out,border-color .25s ease;
}

.secondary-menu-links li:last-child a {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.secondary-menu-links > .dropdown > a > .caret {
    margin-left: 8px;
}

.secondary-menu-links li a .fa {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto 3px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.secondary-menu-links .open > a, .secondary-menu-links .open > a:focus, .secondary-menu-links .open > a:hover, .secondary-menu-links li a:focus, .secondary-menu-links li a:hover, .secondary-menu-links li.active > a, .secondary-menu-links li.active > a:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #fff;
}

.secondary-menu-links > .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.secondary-menu-links li .dropdown-menu {
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px 0;
    border-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0;
}

    .secondary-menu-links li .dropdown-menu li a {
        margin-right: 0;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        color: #303030;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 20px;
        border: none;
    }

.secondary-menu-links > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > li.active > a, .secondary-menu-links > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > li.active > a:focus, .secondary-menu-links > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > li.active > a:hover, .secondary-menu-links > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus, .secondary-menu-links > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #00678d;
}

.secondary-menu-links.navbar-right {
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.secondary-menu-links > li > a.btn {
    padding: 24px 30px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #303030;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-transition: color .25s ease,background-color .25s ease-in-out;
    transition: color .25s ease,background-color .25s ease-in-out;
}

    .secondary-menu-links > li > a.btn:focus, .secondary-menu-links > li > a.btn:hover {
        color: #303030;
        background-color: #fff;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
  </style>
  
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar-fixed-top">
        <div id="menu">
        <div class="menu--topbar">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="menu-topbar--contact">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">                        
                        <li><a style="color:#fff" href="MAILTO:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><span href="mailto:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"></span>EMAILXXXXX</a></li>
                        <li><a style="color:#fff" href="tel:XXXXXXXXXX"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i><span href="tel:XXXXXXXXX"></span> XXXXXXXXX</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>                 
            </div>
        </div>

            <nav id="secondaryMenu" class="navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#secondaryNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="secondaryNavbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
                    <div class="login-btn hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm"> <a href="#" class="btn">Nefsani</a> </div>
                </div>
                <div id="secondaryNavbar" class="reset-padding navbar-collapse collapse ">
                    <ul class="secondary-menu-links nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="OverMezelf-Opleiding.aspx">Over mezelf</a></li>                    
                        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="relatietherapie.aspx" data-toggle="dropdown">Mijn aanbod<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="relatietherapie.aspx">relatietherapie</a></li>
                                <li><a href="individueletherapie.aspx">individuele therapie </a></li>
                                <li><a href="persoonlijkeconsultgesprekken.aspx">persoonlijke consultgesprekken</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="TariefEnTerugbetaling.aspx">Tarieven en terugbetaling</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.aspx">Contacteer mij</a></li>                     
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="secondary-menu-links nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-xs">
                        <li><a href="Default.aspx" class="btn">Nefsani</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
  
<div class="container">
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: May i ask what you have changed so i know for in the future

Answer (score 0):

You may be using outdated version of bootstrap link to import its javascript file. After updating the link, the problem was solved for me.

Hope it helps someone!